# Display sqflite database data as table in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I made a sqflite database and made `query()` function to print the data in console

```
 _query() async {
            final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
            debugPrint('query all rows:');
            for (final row in allRows) {
              debugPrint(row.toString());
            }
          }
```

I need to view this data in a table or tableview (either through a list method or directly)...

format of data.

```
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE $table (
        $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
        $columnBatch TEXT NOT NULL,)''');
```

Comment: can you include the format of data you have then i will try to answer your question

Comment: yes... now I have added it above

Comment: It has id , name , and batch columns

Comment: attach the result you are getting from the query

Comment: Result of query() : {_id: 1, name: Dan John Bobby, batch: CA20}

Answer (score 1):

first create a model class like this

> Model Class:

```
class ModelClass {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? batch;

  ModelClass({this.id, this.name, this.batch});

  ModelClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['_id'];
    name = json['name'];
    batch = json['batch'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['_id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['batch'] = batch;
    return data;
  }
}
```

now from the method when extracting data from the database and return the list of Model like this:

```
Future<List<ModelClass>> _query() async {
  final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
  debugPrint('query all rows:');
  final List<ModelClass> modelClassList = [];
  allRows.forEach((row) {
    modelClassList.add(ModelClass.fromJson(row));
  });
  return modelClassList;
}
```

and in then create a FutureBuilder in which you can display all the data in the list like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _query(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final List<ModelClass> modelClassList =
            snapshot.data as List<ModelClass>;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: modelClassList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(modelClassList[index].name ?? " "),
              subtitle: Text(modelClassList[index].batch ?? " "),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text(modelClassList[index].id.toString()),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you if not then let me know